# Variable does not get replaced inside ' ' in a bash function

Tags: bash

I need to put this

```
gulp --cordova 'prepare ios' --buildVars='version:${buildVarVersion},target:${target}' --res=${target}
gulp --cordova 'build ios --device --release --codeSignIdentity=${codeSignIdentity}' --no-build --res=${target}
```

inside a function. The single quotes need to be preserved. I'm struggling with the correct escaping. I've tried:

```
function buildIPA() {
  CFBundleIdentifier=$1
  target=$2
  version=$3
  codeSignIdentity=$4

  buildVarVersion="public";
  if [ "$version" = "enterprise" ]; then
      buildVarVersion="private";
  fi

  gulp --cordova \'prepare ios\' --buildVars=\'version:${buildVarVersion},target:${target}\' --res=${target}
  gulp --cordova \'build ios --device --release --codeSignIdentity=${codeSignIdentity}\' --no-build --res=${target}

};
```

But it seems that this translates to:

```
gulp --cordova prepare ios --buildVars=version:${buildVarVersion},target:${target} --res=${target}
```

removing the single quotes alltogether.

Comment: to be expanded, write them within double quotes.

Comment: Without any quotes (double or single) something like `\'prepare ios\'` will be *two* arguments to the `gulp` program. Put everything that you need to be a single argument to `gulp` in double quotes, and drop the backslashes to escape the single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace all

```
gulp --cordova \'prepare ios\' --buildVars=\'version:${buildVarVersion},target:${target}\' --res=${target}
```

with

```
gulp --cordova "prepare ios" --buildVars="version:${buildVarVersion},target:${target}" --res=${target}
```

otherwise word-splitting (at blanks) will cause your commands to receive more args than you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the part containing the variables in double quotes:

```
gulp --cordova 'prepare ios' --buildVars="'version:${buildVarVersion},target:${target}'" --res=${target}
gulp --cordova "'build ios --device --release --codeSignIdentity=${codeSignIdentity}'" --no-build --res=${target}
```